# How to remotely ssh on to a linux server install/run on an Android device by Complete Linux Installer

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have installed and running an ubuntu server on an Android device by using [Complete Linux Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid&hl=en). The android server runs ok. I can log in to the server on the Android device by using terminal simulator app.

What I want is ssh on to that Android-Linux-server from remote. I have got the server ip from ifconfig, which is 182.168.1.17. I have the root password.

So I do `ssh root@182.168.1.17` on a pc. I can ping that ip on the pc. But I got ssh port 22 connection refused.

What should I do?

Comment: did you install openssh server?? -- https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html

Comment: @Tasos yes. I've installed openssh server from apt-get. The problem is `systemctl: command not found.` I cant register sshd to startup service. But I had launched ssh service in current login session.

Comment: Check here in regards to SSH -- https://www.gadgetdaily.xyz/run-linux-on-android-part-1/

Comment: I am facing the same issue while running Ubuntu on Android. I can ssh from my Android to the guest Ubuntu. But not from outside

Answer (score 0):

1) Maybe you need to do [port forwarding](https://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for)  on your router / modem 
 
2) Or maybe you are behind [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)
Make sure that your ip is public but if your ip is behind NAT, you can use tor and torsocks to get access to your phone